# Direction and Speed control using same throttle

Tags: motor, dc, control, potentiometer, speed

I have a 24VDC permanent magnet motor such as those commonly found on a mobility scooter. I would like to be able to control both the speed and the direction of the motor with the same throttle control without the need to use a reverse switch. Current mobility scooters use whats known as a 'Wigwag' potentiometer or throttle potentiometer to achieve this.

[image]

**My question is how can I control the speed and direction the of the motor using the same throttle control without a reverse switch?**

I have found a simple circuit online which looks useful however this circuit doesn't allow for the modification of the acceleration/deceleration rate or other parameters which I would like to able to modify.

[image]

Can I use a micro controller with the throttle voltage as the input and then step up the output currents and voltages somehow?

Comment: Analog voltage to PWM connected to a H bridge.

Comment: Let a microprocessor generate the acceleration/deceleration ramps and PWM signal. A simple pot on an analog input measures (say) 0 to 5V. Simply set (say) 1.0 to 1.5V as Off, voltages below 1 as reverse (0V is the highest reverse speed) and voltages above 1V as Forward (5V being full speed). The choices are somewhat arbitrary but I am guessing you want a lower top speed in reverse...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons your sample circuit are unsuitable:

- You don't have dual power supplies (±24 V) on your scooter.
- The voltage control method is wasteful. At half voltage the output transistors will waste as much power as the motor is using.
- The potentiometer doesn't mechanically run end to end. (See Figure 1.)

[image]

*Figure 1. A wigwag throttle pot for a mobility scooter. Note that only a small portion of the potentiometer's 330° travel is used - maybe ±30°.*

The solutions to this are:

- Design for single rail supply. This will require use of a H-bridge to enable reversing current direction in the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW9G6Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. A simplified schematic of a H-bridge. With switches 1 and 4 closed as shown the motor will run in one direction. By opening 1 and 4 and closing 2 and 3 the motor can be made run in the opposite direction. To stop the motor open all switches. In practice the switches will be replaced by transistors.*

- Instead of controlling current by gradually turning on Q1/Q2 we will use PWM (pulse-width modulation). In this scheme the motor is pulsed between full power and zero power very quickly and the width of the pulse adjusted in proportion to the desired speed.

[image]

*Figure 3. A PWM signal going from 80% to 20% to 80% to zero. If the pulse frequency is high relative to the reaction time of the motor then very smooth control is obtained with low losses in the switching transistors.*

The best approach will be to use a micro-controller to read the potentiometer, calculate the desired output level using a simple acceleration-limiting algorithm, convert it to PWM and output it to a suitable H-bridge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2facb5W.png)</sup>

*Figure 4. Crude block diagram of PWM control system.*

Code tasks:

- Read potentiometer and normalise or scale to, for example, -100 to +100. You should probably add a deadband in the centre to prevent creep or running current through the motor when stopped. e.g.:

  ```
  0 ------------------------- mid ------------------------- 330°  
             ^ max reverse          max forward ^  
             -100 -------- 0 ---- 0 -------- +100 scaled output
  ```
- Using this strategy will require a definite movement of the wigwag before current is switched on.
- I suspect that the motor will be rather weak and that even with wigwag full-on from rest that acceleration isn't likely to be a problem. If it is then add a routine:

  ```
  // Very crude pseudo-code!
  int v, a, pwm;                 // velocity and acceleration and pwm
  ww = getScaledInput;           // wigwag
  if (ww > 0) {
      if (ww > pwm) {            // we need to accelerate to pwm
          pwm = pwm + accel;
      }
      if (ww < pwm) {            // we need to decelerate
          pwm = pwm - accel;
      }
      if (ww == 0) {             // stop
          pwm = 0;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: If I wanted to drive a motor which draws a full load current of 18A Is this circuit still useful? Is it possible to find an H-bridge circuit which is capable of driving a motor which uses the above full load current?

Comment: Yes and yes. You could consider using a relay to reverse the motor connections for direction and then you just need a big MOSFET to control the PWM. I'll let someone else address that.